# How many QHD displays can I connect to one side of the 13" MBP 4 TB 2016?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I own a CTO 13" 2016 MBP w/ 4 ThunderBolt ports and I am in the market for 2 QHD (1440p) external displays.

While the displays themselves are not USB-C / Thunderbolt compatible I was thinking of also buying a "[Satechi Type-C to Dual HDMI Adapter](https://satechi.net/products/type-c-dual-hdmi-adapter)" which would also charge my Mac and theoretically send video to the 2 external displays.

But now I am wondering if the one port strategy provides enough bandwidth to power the 2 displays at full resolution.

If it matters I don't intend on using the internal display at all with this setup.

Comment: The link says it uses 2 USB-C ports not one and it certainly looks like it does.  I noticed that one of the questions in the Question/Answer section is *"Can this be used with a mid-2017 MacBook Pro (dual USB-C on each side) to drive two QHD 2560 x 1440 monitors?"* to which the answer was *"Yes it can, we've tested it and it's great! Enjoy!"*.  You should probably ask them if 2016 MBP is suported.

Comment: Wow that is definitely a niche product? I would avoid it. If I was in your situation I would get something like this. An OWC Travel Dock (allows charging pass thru, and other handy ports and features) and a USB-c to HDMI display adapter with 4K support TBO I would just get two of those, but I get the point of not having to use a 3rd Thunderbolt port to charge . Since this thing already uses two ports, why not get something that will be more future proof using the same two ports, and may work on your next Computer too.

Comment: For reference here are things I would reccommend as an alternative to the Satechi device. USB-C Travel Dock https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/TCDK5PSG/  and USB-C to HDMI Adpater  https://eshop.macsales.com/item/Macally/UCH4K60/

Comment: FYI another two cable solution (including charging) is Thunderbolt 3 to Dual 4K HDMI Display Adapters, but they are generally not cheap. Nearly $100 on OWC, I found a similar one on NewEgg for ~ $73 https://www.newegg.com/p/2VF-000E-00020?item=9SIA6PF75N9411&source=region&nm_mc=knc-googlemkp-pc&cm_mmc=knc-googlemkp-pc-_-pla-wavlink+technology-_-usb+display+adapters-_-9SIA6PF75N9411&gclid=CjwKCAiAu9vwBRAEEiwAzvjq-zqCnM-5b-eNdAW7ZotHP1yFIV5yteG5KphpfAzb_eljU4KQKLDPBhoChowQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Answer (score 1):

Check out Apples help as indicated below, but unofficially it looks like the Answer is two total external displays can be attached regardless of resolution or which side they are attached. Apple does not really mention QHD but its close enough to 4K, that you probably can't double it with the existing hardware.

> **Check your requirements**
>
> - Check the ports on your Mac to find out whether you need an adapter.
> - Check how many displays your Mac supports: Choose Apple menu  > About This Mac, click Support, then click Specifications. On the webpage that appears, the number of displays your Mac supports appears under Video Support.

Source [Use external monitors with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202351)